# set the datetimepicker value to retrieved value from sqldatareader.getdatetime

Tags: c#

I have a datetime column in my table and when I retrieve that value through `sqldatareader.getdatetime` function the value is not set to the datetime picker.

This is my code

```
dateTimePicker2.Value = read.GetDateTime(0);
```

Comment: Do you get any exception ?

Comment: I didn't get any exception